# Eclipse Indigo: can I use/patch m2e with NTLM?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, ntlm, m2e

We are experiencing an issue with Eclipse Indigo and the new M2E plugin for Maven support.

I installed on the same machine: Maven 3.04 command line, with a patch for NTLM proxy.
This works perfect and seamless.

Then I installed Eclipse Indigo with M2E. I can select an alternative Maven installation (the embedded is 3.02), but for resolution and plugin management, m2e uses no proxy and not the selected maven installation. This is also confirmed in other web results I found.

The internal Maven installation is not working, not even when I use a system wide proxy (CNTLM). I suspect because it uses own settings for the proxy, and I did not patch it for NTLM.

My question is how can I patch the embedded Maven with the same NTLM patch, I used to make Maven 3.04 work seamlessly?

My patch for Maven 3.04:
put: wagon-http-lightweight-2.2.jar in the ext dir under the maven lib dir.